# Catching ODP.NET exception using error codes

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am working on an application which uses `SqlBulkCopy` and `OracleBulkCopy`. Sometimes when I try to insert some records and the records already exist on SQL Server, it throws an exception which I catch like below, and I handle it in a way.

```
 Catch ex As SqlException When ex.ErrorCode = -2146232060
```

However, I am not sure how to catch the exception on OracleBulkCopy which comes with error code: `ORA-26026`.

This is the structure I'm trying to use:

```
        Try
            'code
        Catch ex As SqlException When ex.ErrorCode = -2146232060
            'Handle SQL
        Catch ex As OracleException When ex.Number = 26026
            'Handle Oracle
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Handle General errors
        End Try
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

An `OracleException` (Microsoft implementation) has a [`Code`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleexception.code(v=vs.110).aspx) property. You can use that to match `26026`:

```
if (ex.Code == 26026)
{ ... }
```

The Oracle implementation of the `OracleException` has a [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B28089_01/OracleExceptionClass.htm#i1007958) property:

```
if (ex.Number == 26026)
{ ... }
```

Comment: Patrick, I tried to catch it like "Catch ex As OracleException When ex.Number = 26026" but it won't go in that block. It goes to the general Exception block directly. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the exception type then? Did you place the exception block above all others?

Comment: I have edited my question to show you the try/catch blocks structure.

Comment: @nectarines: Are you sure the error is an Oracle error? What is `ex.GetType()` when you `catch (Exception ex)`?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, after debugging, the .net code for the particular error of ORA-26026 is -2147467259

So I catch like this:

```
Catch ex As OracleException When ex.ErrorCode = -2147467259
```

Comment: But what is it's `Number` / `Code`? You should actually use that one, since it is more controlled.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have used the debugger to view the details. Here is what I found. Do you think it's a good idea to use it like this?        ORA-26026: unique index DBOUSB.CHEQUES_PK initially in unusable state"}
    _HResult: -2147467259
    _message: "External component has thrown an exception."
    CoreError: 2
    ErrorCode: -2147467259
    Errors: Count = 2
    HResult: -2147467259
    IsRecoverable: False
    IsTransient: False
    Number: -2754
    Source: "Oracle Data Provider for .NET"
     TargetSite: {Void PerformBulkCopy()}

Comment: I suggest to use the Code / Number.

Comment: `ex.Number == 26026` is directly tight to `ORA-26026`. How are you ever going to find back `-2147467259`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman So you are saying I better use: Catch ex As OracleException   and then If ex.Number = -2754 Then etc? The number -2754 is the error I found when debugging. The ORA-26026 does not appear anywhere in the "?ex" immediate window (exception details)

Comment: Hmm. I will take a look tomorrow when I am back in the office.